# Get inline css of an element if there is any (no Internal or External css)

Tags: jquery

Trying to find a way to retrieve `inline css` of an element if there is any **applied**. But no internal/external css applied on the element. For example-

```js
$('#get-inline').val( $('#myh1').css('padding-top') );
```

```css
#myh1{
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h1 id="myh1" style="font-size:30px;">Heading 1</h1>
<input type="text" id="get-inline" />
```

In above code its retrieving the css applied using the `#myh1`. But i need it to return `null` or `""`. No `0` or `NaN` or anything else.

If i use `$('#myh1').attr('style');` it will return all inline css. But i need a way to get **specific** css i need to.

Is there way to achieve what i'm trying to? Please help

Looking for a jQuery solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get value of any internal css using this script: Try this:

Jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/hfud139c/

html:

```
<div id="myh1" style="padding-top:10px;height:10px;">Content</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$.fn.inlineStyle = function (prop) {
         var styles = this.attr("style"),
             value;
         styles && styles.split(";").forEach(function (e) {
             var style = e.split(":");
             if ($.trim(style[0]) === prop) {
                 value = style[1];           
             }                    
         });   
         return value;
    };


    var width = $("#myh1").inlineStyle("padding-top");
```

Comment: not internal. need to get inline only. No external or internal

Comment: yes  i was meant inline css

Comment: can u create a jsfiddle plz? its not working when i connect on my code.

Comment: see here:  https://jsfiddle.net/hfud139c/

Comment: Your function working great in JSFiddle. But when i use the function inside 1 of my script's function, i'm getting `NaN` if the css not applied. For example - `var width = $("#myh1").inlineStyle("margin-top");`

Comment: can you give me your myh1 tag html with inline style?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110011/discussion-between-xahed-kamal-and-dhara-parmar).

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <div id="target" style="color: red; background-color: yellow">
        Lorem ipsum <a href='#'>dolor</a> sit amet cosectetur...
    </div>
    <script>
        function get_inline_stylesheet(source)
        {
            // clone node, so that future changes won't affect the original
            // the (true) parameter is not needed, except if you judge it necessary
            source = source.cloneNode(true)
            // disable external stylesheet
            source.setAttribute('style', 'all: reset;' + source.getAttribute('style'));
            return source.style;
        }
        var target = document.querySelector('#target');
        var stylesheet = target.style;
        console.log(stylesheet);
        console.log(stylesheet.length); // 2
        console.log(stylesheet[0]); // 'color';
        console.log(stylesheet[1]); // 'background-color';
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Trying to get certain css. not all inline css.

Comment: You should have said, only some css `attribute` & it's not late to correct your post

Comment: guess you didn't read this part -- "If i use $('#myh1').attr('style'); it will return all inline css. But i need a way to get certain css i need to."

Comment: `But i need a way to get certain css`

I'm francophone but didn't that get any `clear & obvious` meaning in english --- yet, I'm working on

Comment: yeah... my bad.. bad English!

Answer (score 0):

Use native `style` property:

```
el.style['padding-top']
```

---

Full code here:

```js
$('#get-inline').val( document.getElementById('myh1').style['padding-top'] );
$('#get-inline2').val(document.getElementById('myh1').style['font-size'] );
```

```css
#myh1{
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h1 id="myh1" style="font-size:30px;">Heading 1</h1>
<input type="text" id="get-inline" />
<input type="text" id="get-inline2" />
```